# issue parsing CSV with german character to php

Tags: php, parsing, csv, special-characters, fgets

```
**$csv_data[] =  iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', utf8_encode(fgets($csvfile, 1024)));**
```

This is what I am doing to get the input data while parsing a csv. My CSV is UTF -8 .

I tried to figure out how to print exact parsing data to php but no luck yet so far

my input is `Stöckl` from CSV but I get `St~APckl` in PHP even after the utf8 encode.

Just to let you know I am trying to get German Characters in php variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Solution -**

This is what fixed my problem -

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and I've changed

```
$csv_data[] =  iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', utf8_encode(fgets($csvfile, 1024)));
```

to

```
$csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
```

Comment: If your file is already UTF-8, why are you utf8_encode'ing it?

Comment: my input,csv files are in UTF 8 format but not the php file. I've edited my post with solution